# convert tf keras model to scikit MLP NN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I am experimenting with training NLTK classifier model with tensorflow and keras, would anyone know if this could be recreated with sklearn neural work MLP classifier? For what I am using ML for I don't think I need tensorflow but something simplier and easier to install/deploy.

Not a lot of wisdom on machine learning wisdom here, any tips greatly appreciated even describing this deep learning tensorflow keras model greatly appreciated.

So my tf keras model architecture looks like this:

```
training = []

random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)

# create train and test lists. X - patterns, Y - intents
train_x = list(training[:,0])
train_y = list(training[:,1])

# Create model - 3 layers. First layer 128 neurons, second layer 64 neurons and 3rd output layer contains number of neurons
# equal to number of intents to predict output intent with softmax
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax'))

# Compile model. Stochastic gradient descent with Nesterov accelerated gradient gives good results for this model
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
```

SO the [sklearn neural network](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html), am I on track at all with this below? Can someone help me I understand what exactly the tensorflow model architecture is and what cannot be duplicated with sklearn. I sort of understand tensorflow is probabaly much more powerful that sklearn that is something more simple.

```
#Importing MLPClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier


model = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(128,64),activation ='relu',solver='sgd',random_state=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just google converting a keras model to pytorch, there is quite a bit of tutorials out there for that... It doesnt look easy but maybe worth the effort for what ever you need it for...

Going down this road just using sklearn MLP neural network ***I can get good enough results with sklearn...*** without the hassle of getting tensorflow installed properly.

Also on a cloud linux instance tensorflow requires a LOT more memory and storage than a FREE account can do on pythonanywhere.com but free account seems just fine with sklearn

When experimenting with sklearn MLP NN for whatever reason better results just leaving architecture as default and playing around with the learning rate.

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

model = MLPClassifier(learning_rate_init=0.0001,max_iter=9000,shuffle=True).fit(train_x, train_y)
```